# Como fazer um JOIN entre duas tabelas de dois bancos de dados distintos?

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho os dados pessoais (login, senha, nome, etc.) dos usuários em um servidor diferente do que utilizarei em um novo projeto.  Eu gostaria de saber como posso cruzar informações entre duas tabelas, de bancos de dados em servidores diferentes, com credenciais de login diferentes também. Pretendo utilizar apenas os recursos PDO / MySQLi para fazer estas conexões, já que utilizo *shared hosts*.

Exemplo do que queria, em conceito:

```sql
SELECT * FROM `serverLocal`.`banco`.`tabela` 
  INNER JOIN `serverRemoto`.`banco`.`tabela` 
  ON `serverLocal`.`banco`.`tabela`.`uniqid` = `serverRemoto`.`banco`.`tabela`.`uniqid`
WHERE `serverRemoto`.`banco`.`tabela`.`email` = 'foo@baz.com';
```

Neste exemplo, os registros se relacionam através de `uniqid`'s que são iguais para as linhas com conteúdos relacionados.

Pensei em criar uma API REST, mas não sei como utilizar estas informações em um `JOIN`, por exemplo. Como fazer isto funcionar? Quais outras soluções seriam relevantes para resolver este problema, e porque? O PDO / MySQLi já traz algum recurso nativo para que possa "unir" duas conexões a bancos em servidores distintos?

Comment: A exemplo, sites como o Stack Exchange, creio que não esteja tudo no mesmo *servidor*, mas ainda há a interação entre os sites da rede. Exemplo: Estou no SOpt, e ao abrir o SOen, já estou logado lá também. Há o cruzamento das informações de perfil, etc.

Comment: Na verdade eu queria um jeito de não sair copiando a mesma informação em vários bancos de dados de servidores da rede, no caso, informações de login, por exemplo.

Comment: Eu posso estar enganado, mas eu não vejo isso como uma boa prática. Não precisa sair replicando tudo pra cada banco que uma app usar. Mas você pode buscar essas informações pontuais de outros modos, como as alternativas que o Emerson Rocha Luiz citou.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Tente utilizar [Federated tables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/federated-storage-engine.html), você cria uma réplica da tabela 'apontando' para o banco remoto.

Exemplo:

```
CREATE TABLE federated_tabela (
    codigo INT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    nome   VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL
)
ENGINE=FEDERATED
DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
CONNECTION='mysql://usuario:senha@127.0.0.1:3306/banco/tabela';
```

Depois é só fazer o `join` normal.

Mais informações [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11686347).

Comment: Eu enfrentaria algum problema de desempenho, ou ACID?

Comment: Quando é utilizado `Federated tables` não fica nenhum dado na tabela local, toda query é executada no banco remoto. Sua performace vai depender da conexão e do processamento do banco remoto. Porém `Federated tables` possui outras limitações também que pode ser visto aqui: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/federated-limitations.html

Comment: "There is no way for the FEDERATED engine to know if the remote table has changed. The reason for this is that this table must work like a data file that would never be written to by anything other than the database system. The integrity of the data in the local table could be breached if there was any change to the remote database."

Comment: Isso não tem a ver com o desempenho, o que acontece é você criar uma tabela local com 1 campo chamado `codigo` e no banco remoto essa única coluna mudar o nome para `id` nisso você "quebra" a tabela.

Answer (score 14):

`Federated tables`, é uma boa opção, mas se para seu caso ela falhar por alguma limitação, você tem pelo menos mais três opções

### Aplicação próxima de um banco de dados acessar diretamente o outro banco de dados

Um jeito simples é fazer sua linguagem acessar primeiro a tabela local, ver quais dados deve obter da tabela remota, e então acessar a tabela remota e obter somente os dados de interesse. Não é um JOIN a nível de banco de dados, mas sim na aplicação. É simples e a aproximação típica de ser feita quando a complexidade.

**Vantagens**

- Simples. Funciona até em hospedagens compartilhadas

**Desvantagens**

- Exige maior trabalho na aplicação. É bem mais simples que a opção seguinte, e pode ser mais simples que a ultima
- É menos flexível que replicação de tabela

### Mudar sua aplicação, de modo que APIs se conversem e troquem informações

Você pode criar uma API próxima de cada banco de dados que pode ser acessada pelo outro banco de dados (como um REST service) ou então unificar o acesso as tabelas compartilhadas em um serviço único.

Um caso comum de uso desta é autenticação de usuário, aonde apenas inicialmente os dados são obtidos, mas não é um acesso constante.

**Vantagens**

- Para alguns casos, como dados de usuário e autenticação, a centralização poderia ser feita em LDAP, e alguns sistemas já tem código pronto para LDAP
- Permite acesso demais lugares sem precisar passar a senha do seu banco de dados direto
- Permite checagens adicionais, mais fáceis de fazer se você domina mais sua linguagem do que o SQL
- Permite cache

**Desvantagens**

- É complexo de implementar
- Não permite JOIN
- Exige reescrita significativa das rotinas que deseja

### Replicação do banco de dados

Esse método é parecido com `Federated tables`, porém você troca complexidade adicional por performance imediata e vantagens no caso do host remoto estar inacessível e evitar o indefejávem **Ponto Único de Falha**.

[Veja documentação de como fazer replicação](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication-howto.html).

**Vantagens**

- Permite todo tipo de operação comparado de uma tabela normal, inclusive JOINs
- Evita **Ponto Único de Falha**. Mesmo que o servidor remoto fique inacessível, você ainda terá cópia de segurança dos dados
- É mais simples de configurar do que criar uma API REST

**Desvantagens**

- Espaço de disco é maior. O mesmo conteúdo estará armazenado em bancos de dados diferentes (*não costuma ser um grande problema perto das vantagens*)
- É necessário ter privilégios de `SUPER`, o que impede de ser usado caso você use hospedagens compartilhadas do banco de dados.

Comment: Boa explicação das várias opções