# Como fazer um INNER JOIN entre dois bancos diferentes no mesmo servidor no MYSQL?

Tags: mysql

Gostaria de jazer um `INNER JOIN` entre duas tabelas distintas porém que estão no mesmo servidor. Seria algo do tipo?

```
INNER JOIN BANCOA.tabelaA.colunaA ON BANCOA.tabelaA.colunaA = BANCOB.tabelaB.colunaB
```

Lembrando que estou fazendo isso no *MYSQL* e as tabelas estão no mesmo servidor.

Comment: Dá uma olhada aqui -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144051/selecting-data-from-two-different-servers-in-sql-server

Comment: @FelipeRodrigues se a minha resposta não ajudar tente detalhar melhor o seu problema.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A única coisa que tinha de fazer era remover a primeira `**colunaA**` que tem no query, exemplo simples:

```
SELECT * 
FROM banco1.tabela1
INNER JOIN banco2.tabela1 ON banco1.tabela1.campo1=banco2.tabela1.campo1
```

Apenas precisa de fazer o `select` anterior para funcionar tudo bem.

> Mais informação sobre [INNER JOIN](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp).

Se quiser mais informação sobre `select` a tabelas em servidores diferentes veja aqui em [PT](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4456/como-fazer-um-join-entre-duas-tabelas-de-dois-bancos-de-dados-distintos) em [EN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11684956/i-need-to-join-table-from-other-database-and-sometimes-other-server/11686347#11686347).

Answer (score 3):

Considerando que o usuário do banco possui as devidas permissões, sim.

Conforme pode ser visto [neste tópico](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5698378/mysql-join-between-tables-in-2-different-databases) (inglês), considerando uma base A e uma base B, pode-se fazer

```
SELECT <...> FROM A.tabelaA TA JOIN B.tabelaB TB ON TA.colunaA = TB.colunaB;
```