# Consulta SQL em 2 banco de dados em servidores (mysql) diferentes

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, select

Olá.

Primeiramente, deixo claro que não sei se isso é possível.

Estou tentar fazer uma consulta SQL onde preciso dos dados da união (INNER JOIN) de 02 tabelas que estão em servidores diferentes (Um servidor Local e outro Servidor Remoto).

Quero fazer no PHP usando mysqli. Mas já tentei de tudo e não consegui.

Se alguém souber e puder me ajudar ficarei muito grato.

Desde já, agradeço.

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/245824/como-fazer-um-inner-join-entre-dois-bancos-diferentes-no-mesmo-servidor-no-mysql

Comment: Olá Amigo. Obrigado pela resposta, mas infelizmente não é o que eu quero. Pelo que intendi no link que você mandou, esse método só funciona em banco de dados locais. No meu caso um banco é local e o outro é remoto.